# How to create a new Promise with child type B when the function I want to call expects parent type A

Tags: typescript, cordova-plugins, typescript-typings

I'm currently adding types in our Angular project, using Cordova file plugin. In order to list all the directories at a specific path, we use the following code :

```
const directory: any = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory + path, resolve, reject);
});
```

I know that `directory` is a `DirectoryEntry` object, which is an interface extending `Entry`. My problem is that using `const directory: DirectoryEntry` makes TypeScript complain.

```
Impossible to assign type 'Entry' to type 'DirectoryEntry | PromiseLike<DirectoryEntry>'.
```

How can I properly do this ? I know that I could simply let `directory` be `any` and cast it latter, but still, I'm curious to see how this problem could be solved.

Thanks a lot for all your answers.

Comment: Promises need to be typed as such in TypeScript. Have you tried: 
`const directory: Promise<DirectoryEntry>`

Comment: I'm awaiting the created Promise, so the type of `directory` is `DirectoryEntry`. And even with your suggested syntax, I still get the same error, as I commented bellow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to pass the type parameter to the promise constructor - like so:

```js
const directory = await new Promise<DirectoryEntry>((resolve, reject) => {
  window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory + path, resolve, reject);
});
```

Edit: Ok - I see your problem is that resolveLocalFileSystemURL is telling you that the callback passed to it's second parameter is going to be called with `Entry`, not `DataDirectory`.

Because resolveLocalFileSystemURL will pass an object to resolve, it can't tell if it's a directory or a file (and - your file structure might change).

If you want to ignore the warning, I'd say something like:

```js
const entry = await new Promise<Entry>((resolve, reject) => {
  window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory + path, resolve, reject);
});

// We know this path is a directory
const directory = entry as DirectoryEntry;
```

or

```js
const directory = await new Promise<DirectoryEntry>((resolve, reject) => {
  window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory + path, entry => resolve(entry as DirectoryEntry), reject);
});
```

A safer alternative is to actually check it is a directory, and handle as appropriate, using a [type-predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates):

```js
function isDirectory(entry: Entry): entry is DirectoryEntry {
  return entry.isDirectory;
}

const entry = await new Promise<Entry>((resolve, reject) => {
  window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory + path, resolve, reject);
});

if (isDirectory(entry)) {
  // In this scope, TS has now narrowed entry to DirectoryEntry safely 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is still the same : `Argument of type '(value: DirectoryEntry | PromiseLike<DirectoryEntry>) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(entry: Entry) => void'.`

Comment: @informaticienzero - I see what you mean now - updated

Comment: Good call @mbdavis on the TS scope, always forget that feature!